# How to play video player on all platforms

Tags: html5-video

When i try to play video on android 2.2 it says "Sorry video cannot be play".
here is the code i am using

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="576" height="362" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="http://www.tazsoldev.com/8cow/wp-content/themes/8cow/images/splash.png">
  <source src="http://www.tazsoldev.com/8cow/wp-content/themes/8cow/frontpage1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="http://www.tazsoldev.com/8cow/wp-content/themes/8cow/frontpage1.theora.ogv" type='video/ogv; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
 <!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->
  <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="576" height="362" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://www.tazsoldev.com/8cow/wp-content/themes/8cow/images/splash.png", {"url": "http://www.tazsoldev.com/8cow/wp-content/themes/8cow/frontpage1.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
    <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
    <img src="http://www.tazsoldev.com/8cow/wp-content/themes/8cow/images/splash.png" width="576" height="362" alt="Poster Image"
      title="No video playback capabilities." />
  </object>
</video>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try .webm? I've had videos playing on Android before fine.. what happens if you try and load the video in the browser manually? For instance - just trying the whole address to the video...

Does it work in a regular browser?

Answer (score -1):

I think that Android Doesn't Support MP4 extension, and I'm not sure about it.
try a other extension or an other frequency of the video.

Comment: Not true, Android *does* support mp4.  But there are restrictions on the codec parameters.  To make this even more complex, there is a degree of variance between devices and Android versions.